# Mailchimp tag API silently failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm calling the Node.js Mailchimp API like so:

```js
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');
const md5 = require('md5');

// ...

const resp = await mailchimp.lists.updateListMemberTags(
  mailchimpListId,
  md5('my@email.com'),
  { tags: [{ name: 'Tag Name', status: 'active' }] }
);

(resp === null) // true
```

- The subscriber exists
- The md5 library is providing the valid md5 hash (confirmed by calling `getListMemberTags` successfully)
- No error is being generated

But the response is null, and the tag is not being added to the subscriber.

Any ideas as to why it might be silently failing, and if so, how I can debug it?

(If relevant, this is all being run within an Auth0 Custom Action.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Buck at Mailchimp, I found the solution. Unlike most API calls in the library, `updateListMemberTags` needs a body wrapper like so:

```js
const resp = await mailchimp.lists.updateListMemberTags(
  mailchimpListId,
  md5('my@email.com'),
  { body: { tags: [{ name: 'Tag Name', status: 'active' }] } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still experiencing this, here is the updated Documentation for this, and will be most up-to-date.

[Mailchimp Docs](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/organize-contacts-with-tags/)

I just went in circles for like 4 hours before running into this fix. Hope it helps.